# Is the bold sentence in the paragraph a double negative?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

the following paragraph is from the book *Mr. Popper's Penguins* page 32:

> Mrs. Popper had gone marketing for canned shrimps for the penguin, so
>   that Mr. Popper was alone in the kitchen to explain to the service man
>   what he wanted done to the refrigerator.
>
> The service man put his tool bag down on the kitchen floor, looked
>   at the refrigerator, and then at Mr. Popper, who, to tell the truth,
>   had not shaved yet and was not very tidy.
>
> “Mister,” he said, ***“you don’t need no ventilating holes in that
>   there door.”***
>
> “It’s my icebox, and I want some holes bored in the door,” said Mr.
>   Popper.
>
> They argued about it for quite a while. Mr. Popper knew that to get
>   the service man to do what he wanted, all he had to do was to explain
>   that he was going to keep a live penguin in the icebox, and that he
>   wanted his pet to have plenty of fresh air, even though the door was
>   closed all night. He felt a little stubborn about explaining, however.
>   He didn’t want to discuss Captain Cook with this unsympathetic service
>   man, who was already staring at Mr. Popper as if he thought Mr. Popper
>   was not quite right in his head.

What is the meaning of the bold sentence '***you don't need no ventilating holes in that there door.'***?

According to my research on google, this sentence is a double negative, and it means you need ventilation holes in that there door. But according to the response of Mr. Popper, I think the service man is actually questioning Mr. Popper about his decision. So the sentence should be in a rising tone. Is that right?

Also, what is the meaning of 'that there'? Does it mean 'in that door there'？

Answer (score 3):

No, it's actually just dialect.  *"You don't need no ..."* is the same as *"you don't need **any** ..."*  Example:

> "Hey!" he yelled.  "You **don't** got **no** business coming here." (= *"You don't have any reason to come here"*)

So. in this case, the serviceman is telling Mr. Popper that he doesn't need to have *any* holes drilled into his icebox.

This particular structure is found in both British and American English dialects (with some differences) and is generally considered lower- or working-class.  Because it is not standard English, you should probably not use this structure until you fully understand its nuance.

*"That there"* is also dialect.  It simply means *that*.

> "Well," drawled the farmer, "**that there** mule might be the stubbornest critter I ever did see." (= *"that mule is the most stubborn animal I have ever known"*)

This structure is found in American English dialects of the South and Midwest, and is usually considered *rural*.

Historical note:  Today, "icebox" is sometimes used as a synonym for "refrigerator".  However, when the book was written in 1938, [people really did have wooden boxes in which they put large blocks of ice, in order to keep food fresh.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icebox)

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer and correction on my post. It's really helpful.

Comment: I can accept 'You ain't got', 'you don't got' is not grammatical to me.

Comment: @user178049  it's not grammatical.   It's dialect, and [not uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=you+don%27t+got+no&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)